# Is there any way to customize AWS CodeCommit notification messages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

Following the user guide (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-repository-email-create.html), I was able to set up CodeCommit email notification on pull request for a repo.

But the problem is the email message is not at all straight forward to read. Is there anyway to customize the notification messages sent via AWS SNS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use InputTransformers to change the email content:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatch-Events-Input-Transformer-Tutorial.html

from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59283052/aws-code-commit-simple-notification-service-is-there-a-way-to-get-better-format

The content of each CodeCommit message can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/monitoring-events.html